# How to return an array of values with Ajax using ASP classic

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp-classic

I'm working with ASP classic and Javascript. I have a javascript function where i use a library to create PDFs, but to get values from database I use AJAX. When I make an AJAX call, how would I return an array or hashmap of values, or even each variable separately back to the function from where I make a call???

EDIT:
Those values that i want to get from AJAX call, I'd like to use later in the same function to create a pdf.

EDIT:

> function make_me_a_pdf(id, izbor, prejemnik){

```
    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!
    var spr;

try{
    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e){
    // Internet Explorer Browsers
    try{
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e){
            // Something went wrong
            alert("Your browser broke!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}

ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){

        spr = ajaxRequest.responseText;
        document.write(spr);

    }

}

ajaxRequest.open("GET", "getPrejetoNarPodatki.asp", true);
ajaxRequest.send(null);
```

This is the code I wrote to make an AJAX call. In getPrejetoNarPodatki.asp the only thing that is writen is:

> response.write("tralala")

...In this case it saves "tralala" to variable spr and i can use it... My question is how to get more values back so I can use them later in the function make_me_a_pdf() ??

Comment: Any code or something to show us?

Comment: Seems like you are asking how to return a JSON value like {"prop1":"value1","prop2":"value2"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for everybody who will search for this problem... I solved it!

I used JSON method to get the values. I put this into the javascript function:

```
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){

    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){

    var txt = ajaxRequest.responseText;
    var obj = eval ("(" + txt + ")");
    alert(obj.employees[1].firstName);      
    }
}
```

In the AJAX file i put this lines of code:

```
text = "{""employees"":[{""firstName"":""John"",""lastName"":""Doe""},                {""firstName"":""Anna"",""lastName"":""Smith""}]}"

response.write(text)
```

Make sure you use double quotes. The eval() function uses the JavaScript compiler which will parse the JSON text and produce a JavaScript object (taken from w3schools). The printed name in alert is "Anna"

Answer (score 1):

Return a JSON array which ends up being plain text that you can generate using classic ASP.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to send the PDF response as a URI encoded string after base64 encoding the string and decode it on the client side appropriately. Any examples of how the PDF response is being sent from the server side?

```
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){

        var pdfText = decodeURIComponent(ajaxRequest.responseText);

        var pdf = base64DecToArr(pdfText);
        document.write(pdf);
    }

}

/* Array of bytes to base64 string decoding */

function b64ToUint6 (nChr) {

  return nChr > 64 && nChr < 91 ?
      nChr - 65
    : nChr > 96 && nChr < 123 ?
      nChr - 71
    : nChr > 47 && nChr < 58 ?
      nChr + 4
    : nChr === 43 ?
      62
    : nChr === 47 ?
      63
    :
      0;

}

function base64DecToArr (sBase64, nBlocksSize) {

  var
    sB64Enc = sBase64.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/]/g, ""), nInLen = sB64Enc.length,
nOutLen = nBlocksSize ? Math.ceil((nInLen * 3 + 1 >> 2) / nBlocksSize) * nBlocksSize : nInLen * 3 + 1 >> 2, taBytes = new Uint8Array(nOutLen);

  for (var nMod3, nMod4, nUint24 = 0, nOutIdx = 0, nInIdx = 0; nInIdx < nInLen; nInIdx++) {
    nMod4 = nInIdx & 3;
    nUint24 |= b64ToUint6(sB64Enc.charCodeAt(nInIdx)) << 18 - 6 * nMod4;
    if (nMod4 === 3 || nInLen - nInIdx === 1) {
      for (nMod3 = 0; nMod3 < 3 && nOutIdx < nOutLen; nMod3++, nOutIdx++) {
        taBytes[nOutIdx] = nUint24 >>> (16 >>> nMod3 & 24) & 255;
      }
      nUint24 = 0;

    }
  }

  return taBytes;
}
```